# Google search results page on my Firefox looks different

Tags: firefox, google-search

The Google's Search results page on my FF looks different than the usual page I see on other days. Attached below is the screenshot:

I checked on several other computers and the Google search results page looked normal on them. I'm using Firefox 24.0. This happens only on Firefox Browser on my machine.

[image]

Any reasons for this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in in Firefox but not in Chrome or vice versa? Google tends to manipulate your search results based on your 'interests'. Try logging in or out in both browsers and see if that makes a difference.