# Description text missing from google search

Tags: google-chrome, google-search, google-workspace

[image: wtf google]

As you can see, descriptions are missing from google search. This only occurs on a certain google account which I am signed into (I've cropped that from the image for privacy).

If I use incognito mode or another account, it works fine.

I therefore assume there is a setting in my account, but I have no idea where it is. Please help!

Comment: Possible dup of [Google Chrome only displays URLs of search results--no detailed descriptions any more](https://superuser.com/q/882781) and [Google search results page on my Firefox looks different](https://superuser.com/q/666814)

Comment: Since it  works in Incognito, I assume you have some extension blocking the data. Can you disable your extensions and try again?

Comment: @DavidPostill I just checked that dup. This is similar. The other one is unanswered though and his issue was intermittent across his browser. Mine is local to my account

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy I turned off all extensions; didn't help :(

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It's not related to extensions—it only happens when I'm logged into my Google account. The same problem happens in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. If I'm logged in, there are no descriptions; if I'm logged out, everything works as normal.

Comment: There's a big thread about it on one of Google's forums. No solutions, though: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/vzMQwDcZpTM

Comment: Google seems to have fixed it. I no longer have the problem, and neither to a bunch of posters on the forum.

Comment: I can confirm the issue has been fixed

Answer (score 1):

Google has fixed the issue themselves.

If you're encountering this issue after googles fix. I was able to get some luck by reseting all settings in Chrome.

Happy computing.